# browserstack jenkins pluing error

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, browserstack

I am currently trying to integrate my jenkins with browserstack, but I am getting a strange error, I am not very familiar with java technologies so I am a little lost in here:

```
[BrowserStack] Local: Starting BrowserStack Local...
FATAL: JSONObject["message"] not a string.
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException
at    com.browserstack.automate.ci.jenkins.BrowserStackBuildWrapper.setUp(BrowserStackBuildWrapper.java:61)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:668)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:544)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Jenkins is using OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14) and maven 3.3.9

Looks like it is using the right workspace, however I get the same error even if there are pom files or not

[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testbrowserstack

Comment: OK, now if I disable the browser stack part it builds successfully, wich is probably related to my understanding on how to use this plug-in or maybe the lag of documentation on it. Still I want to make it run in browser stack.

Comment: This issue only occurs when I try BrowserStack Local, however I try with out local, it builds a jar file and I do not think it actually does anything with browserstack.

Comment: So Username and access key were wrong, these aren't the same than the ones for login in the website. Still can not make anythong to work on browserstack, My jenkins job builds a maven project and produces a file.jar, but just that.

Comment: Could you share details on how you are managing the BrowserStackLocal binary via the Jenkins plugin? Are you specifying a path to the binary or you are allowing the plugin to automatically download the binary?Also, since this is a Jenkins plugin for BrowserStack. I suggest contacting BrowserStack Support.

Comment: @Mukesh Tiwari, HI!, I let the plugin to download it and do anything, I will send a mail to them and see if they have better information than the one in the website.

Comment: @YerisAntonio Did you get this issue resolved? I have the same problem.